# Machine Learning, GA + BP or GA with huge NN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Sorry for the poor title,

I'm currently studying ML and I want to focus on a problem using the toolset I have acquired, which exludes reinforcement learning.

I want to create a NN that takes a simple 2D game level ( think of mario in the simplest case, simple fitness function, simple controls and easy feature selection)  and outputs key  sequence.

Since we don't know the correct key sequence(ks), I see 2 options,

1-) I find that out using genetic algorithm and use backprop or similar algorithms to associate levels with key sequences and predict a KS for a new level

2-) I build a huge NN and use genetic algorithm to solve whole internal structure of it.

What are the pros and cons of each approach? Why should I implement one instead of the other? Please remember that I'm fairly new to the topic and want to solve this problem with what I've learned until now, basics really.

Comment: Not a good question for SO.  why don't you try both and tell us what you learn?  I don't see what a genetic algorithm is going to do for you here.  Run through the NN and see what it gives you.

Comment: @duffymo I will try both, but currently I'm implementing image processing part. I was hoping someone could lay out cases in which one or the other would be advantageous. Cases which are not limited to this question.

Answer (score 1):

What you are suggesting is in essence reinforcement learning, e.g. trying out "semi random" combinations and then using rewards to learn the network. The first approach is classical reinforcement learning and the other one is reinforcement learning using a neural network.

If you want to solve the topic like this there are plenty of tutorials and github repos available to help you solve this problem, with a simple google search.